# Check if user like a page without creating facebook app

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-like, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have to check in my script if a user like a facebook page.

I would realize it without Facebook app. I would not create it.

I founded some examples, but they require a Facebook app, and that user gives it the correct permission.

Can you help me? Is it possible?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: You want to steal user's information without their permission?

Comment: `Can you help me?` **No** `Is it possible?` **No**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Facebook API and ask for permission from the user to do this.

**Resources:**

[Facebook API info](http://developers.facebook.com/)

[User info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Answer (score 1):

If your application is an external website, then you need to use the Facebook API and ask for the user_likes permission + valid access and make a POST to USER_ID/likes/PAGE_ID

If your application is a canvas or a tab application, then you can use the signed_request parameters that Facebook send you.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Regards